# angularjs zeros missing within number input

Tags: html, angularjs

I have problem with zeros like above :

in html I have :

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default">
   <label>Numéro</label>
   <input class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 11px;" placeholder="(+33)57 24 05 99" ng-model="produit.telephone">
</div>
```

the model is:

```
telephone: {type: Number, default: null}
```

when I put a number which has zero on the left, it will not be considered.

for instance when I put 0160206576, it will be saved as 160206576

Comment: Numbers simply can't start with a zero, if you need a zero first then it must be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has zeros in the front, it must be stored as a string, like this:

```
 app.controller("main",function($scope){
   $scope.produit.telephone = "0160206576";

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type `number`, for allowing preloading `0`, to `String`

```
telephone: {type: String, default: null}
```